# Basic While Loop sequence of iteration?

Tags: python

For the code below, after the first instance where the IF statement is false (i.e. for i=9), I understand that we go to the print("something") step however, my question is why does it infinitely print "something" and "somethingelse" instead of printing these two just once each then just ending? I mean we have no step after the print of these two that tells it to go back to the if statement and test again with i = 9 (that would lead to an infinite loop)..

```
    i=1
while True:
    if i%9 != 0:
        print ("inside if")
        i +=1
        continue
    print("something")
    print("somethingelse")
```

Comment: Because you forgot break

Comment: basically your algorithm never stops... you haven't gave it a reason for it to stop

Answer (score 1):

Your print statements are inside of a `While True`: loop with no exit criteria.  That is precisely why.

Answer (score 1):

`while True:`

Means that while I do not have a statement somewhere to stop or a `break` to stop the algorithm, it will keep entering in the while loop.

Therefore, what you made is an infinite loop and that's why it keeps printing the same stuff.

```
i=1
while True:
    if i%9 != 0:
        print ("inside if")
        i +=1
        break
print("something")
print("somethingelse")

#output 
"inside if" -> breaks after `i=1` because `1%9=1`
"something"
"somethingelse"
```

```
i=1
kak = True
while kak:
    if i%9 != 0:
        print ("inside if")
        i +=1
        kak = False # --> something to tell the algorithm, hey! stop! 
print("something")
print("somethingelse")
```